# Regression with endogenous dummy variables

Tags: regression, endogeneity, selection-bias

Suppose I have 1,000 observations on variable Y, and I regress Y on just a dummy variable (d), in two different regressions. In the first regression, I set d equal to 0 for the first 500 observations, and 1 for the last 500 observations. In the second regression, I set d equal to 0 when Y is below its own median, and 1 when Y is above its own median. The second regression produces biased estimates, whereas the first regression does not. Why is this? What assumption of linear regression am I violating in the second regression? Below is the R code that I am using.

```
set.seed(1)

y <- rnorm(1000, 5, 1)

d1 <- c(rep(0, 500), rep(1, 500))

d2 <- ifelse(y < median(y), 0, 1)

unbiased_model <- lm(y ~ d1)

biased_model <- lm(y ~ d2)

summary(unbiased_model)

summary(biased_model)
```

Comment: In the first model you get an intercept of about $5$ and a coefficient for $d_1$ of about $0$.  Since the mean of $d_1$ is $\frac12$, this gives an mean estimate for $y$ of about $5$ which you call unbiased. In the second you get an intercept of about $4.2$ and a coefficient for $d_2$ of about $1.6$.   Since the mean of $d_2$ is $\frac12$, this gives an mean estimate for $y$ of about $5$ which you call biased.

Answer (score 0):

So in the first model, there is no correlation between d1 and Y. As Y was randomly generated, setting the first 500 d1 equal to 0 and next 500 equal to 1 is no different than making d1 and Y two uncorrelated (and thus regression coefficient is 0) random variables.

However in the second, there *is* a relationship between d2 and Y. As i-th d2's value is based on if I-th Y value was above or below the median. This creates a dependency between d2 and Y, which is reflected in the nonzero regression coefficient.

Comment: So in both cases we are fitting
y = mu + beta * d1

In d1, because d1 and Y are uncorrelated, beta is 0. This means that
y = mu
So. Y should have the same mean as mu.

But in the case of d2 beta is not 0 so mu doesn't have the same mean.
TLDR: If you select dummy variables using Y, then you introduce a correlation between Y and the dummy variables, which means your regression coefficient is nonzero which impacts your mean.

Comment: As for assumptions, the common ones (like about independent normal errors) ensure that you will get an unbiased estimate of the population's regression line. It doesn't say that your estimate of mu will be the population's mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer my own question, although I'd be grateful if there is a more formal solution. Let: y = a + bD + e. The reason that y is a random variable is because e is a random variable. If D is a nonrandom function of y, then e is a function of D, and thus not independent. When I choose D based on the value of y, I am simultaneously choosing e based on the value of D. The expected value of e is now a function of D. But regression does not know this. It assumes that D and e are independent. Thus, the difference in e, conditional on D, gets forced into b, and b is biased.

```
set.seed(1)

#True mean of y is 5
y <- rnorm(1000, 5, 1)

# Let d1 be the midpoint
d1 <- c(rep(0, 500), rep(1, 500))

#Regression is correct, no difference in mean
summary(lm(y ~ d1))

#Let d2 be a function of y
d2 <- ifelse(y < median(y), 0, 1)

#Regression is incorrect, finds a difference in mean 
summary(lm(y ~ d2))

#Reason is because e is a function of d2
e <- c(rnorm(500, mean(y[y < median(y)]), sd(y[y < median(y)])),
       rnorm(500, mean(y[y > median(y)]), sd(y[y > median(y)])))

y1 <- 0 + e

summary(lm(y1 ~ d1))
```